# Что лучше в цикле: создание нового объекта для выполнения метода или создать один раз и выполнять метод в цикле?

Tags: php

Метод потребляет много памяти.
Вопрос стоит в импорте кучи элементов.
Вопрос риторический.

**UPD 1**

Примерный код:

*Вариант 1:*

```
foreach($arr as $b){
    $a = new myClass();
    $a->myFunc($b);
}
```

*Вариант 2:*

```
$a = new myClass();
foreach($arr as $b){
    $a->myFunc($b);
}
```

**UPD 2**

из-за цикла, скрипт останавливается. Связано это из-за того, что кончается память выделяемая скрипту.
Есть ли способ чистить память?

Comment: какая разница, если тормозит метод, а не создание объекта?

Comment: Может код покажете?

Comment: @Anamnian код добавило, но мне нужно теоретические больше знания, чем практические.

Comment: @Lexx918 метод уже максимально отлажен. Работает на пределе.

Comment: @nar10z зачем вам в цикле $b, если вы его не используете во втором варианте? Или опечатались? Вообще с моей точки зрения второй вариант предпочтительнее, т.к. создание объекта это выделение под него памяти + вызов метода-конструктора. Соответственно практичнее создать метод 1 раз и вызвать его конструктор, чем выделять память n-раз и n-раз вызывать конструктор. А вообще в php есть статические классы? Может стоит этот код переписать если они есть...

Comment: @Anamnian, да опечатался, сейчас исправлюсь.
Спасибо за совет, буду думать дальше над оптимизацией

Comment: в первом варианте циклически выполняется `new`. Собственно, память и уходит... По-памяти, РНР использует умные указатели и чистится если написать `$a=null` (в цикле первого варианта)